# Probelm with spinner and context - Android Java

Tags: android, this, spinner

I'm having trouble launching the app (the app freezes) after adding a Spinner to it.
It probably doesn't get me "Context" properly - probably.
Maybe the problem lies elsewhere, but I cannot verify it at my stage
Before adding Spinner everything worked ok.
Git app code: https://github.com/RemekLago/project_Factory2.git

I will be grateful for any help.

code of main activity:

```
package com.example.projecttech_v4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    private PagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Maszyna01"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Maszyna02"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Maszyna03"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Maszyna04"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Maszyna05"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Maszyna06"));

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        adapter = new PagerAdapter(fragmentManager, getLifecycle());
        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position){
                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
            }
        });

        Spinner spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1_operator);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                (this, R.array.operator, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);

    }
}
```

code: XML mainactivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1_operator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2_data"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3_godzina"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_zatwierdz_operator"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Zatwierdź"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


    </TableRow>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`TableRow` should be a child of `TableLayout` only. exchange `<TableRow` to `<LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` attribute in your XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- TableRow becomes LinearLayout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp">
        
        <!-- spinners and rest of code -->
```

powodzenia